# Mapreduce api giving wrong mapper count

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to get the number of mappers in a mapreduce program by using below piece of code. I get the value for **mapreduce.job.maps as 2** but the program actually launches **6 mappers** as there are 6 small files. Anyone getting similar issue?

**Code**

```
job.getConfiguration().get("mapreduce.job.maps")
```

**Log:**

```
num of mappers : 2 
 ...
17/05/13 06:56:47 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 6
17/05/13 06:56:47 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:6
...
17/05/13 06:56:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1494588725898_0047
17/05/13 06:56:59 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1494588725898_0047 running in uber mode : false
17/05/13 06:56:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
...
17/05/13 06:57:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
17/05/13 06:57:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1494588725898_0047 completed successfully
17/05/13 06:57:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
        File System Counters
        ...
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=6
                Launched reduce tasks=2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue, but the actual behaviour of MapReduce.

The value you get for `mapreduce.job.maps` property is its default value, **`2`**. The number of mapper tasks will always be determined from the File Input Splits, which is **`6`** in this scenario. And to get the actual number of map tasks launched for a job, you have to wait till the job is completed.

Comment: Is there any way i can get the number of input splits in the driver program before the mr program launches? When i am reading data from hive table i can use `hCatInputFormat.getSplits(job).size();` to get num of splits before the mr program launches. Is there a way to do same when i am reading from hdfs files?